# Accessing a child within a child firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is not a duplicate. 
I am trying to access a child within a child in firebase and then putting that child into a recycler adapter. It won't show in the recycler adapter. There is a similar question on here to this but when implementing it, it still doesn't work.

Currently using an adapter, a messages object and a fragment.

```
Fragment Activity

    private ArrayList<Messages> results = new ArrayList<>();
    private void listenForChat() {
        final DatabaseReference userDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUid)
                .child("receivedMessages");
        messageUrlDb = userDb.child("messageUrl");

        messageUrlDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String message = "";
                if (dataSnapshot.child("messageUrl").getValue() != null)
                    message = dataSnapshot.child("messageUrl").getValue().toString();
                Messages obj = new Messages(message, name, image);
                if (!results.contains(obj)) {
                    results.add(obj);
                    messagesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    initializeDisplay();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ChatViewHolders> {


    private List<Messages> mMessageList;
    private List<UserObject> usersList;
    private Context context;
    private DisplayTextFragment displayTextFragment;
    private String message;



    public ChatAdapter(List<Messages> mMessageList, Context context) {

        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public ChatViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, null);
        ChatViewHolders rcv = new ChatViewHolders(v);
        return rcv;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ChatViewHolders holder, int position) {

        holder.messageText.setText(mMessageList.get(position).getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }


    public class ChatViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView messageText, timeSent, mName;
        ImageView mProfile;
        LinearLayout mLayout;

        public ChatViewHolders(View view) {
            super(view);
            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            mLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Firebase database]

I am trying access (messageUrl) users -> receivedMessages -> messageUrl. However as there is a key they I assume it doesn't as far as messagesUrl. For the recycler adapter it needs take in messagesUrl as a string and update accordingly but I just can't do it.

If any more code is needed I can post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you're attaching your `ValueEventListener`:

```
final DatabaseReference userDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUid)
        .child("receivedMessages");
messageUrlDb = userDb.child("messageUrl");

messageUrlDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

If we take the path from this code, you're attaching the listener to `/users/$uid/receivedMessages/messageUrl`. This path doesn't exist in the data you showed, so your `onDataChanged` will get called with an empty snapshot.

If you want to read all messages for the user, you should attach your listener to `/users/$uid/receivedMessages` and parse the snapshot inside `onDataChanged`:

```
final DatabaseReference userDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUid)
        .child("receivedMessages");
userDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userMessages: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: userMessages.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(messageSnapshot.getKey()+": "+messageSnapshot.getChild("messageUrl").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

This loops over the two level of child nodes you have under the user's `receivedMessages` node.